# How to load properties file using system properties

Tags: java, spring

I have a properties file which sits on APPSERVERS HOME directory(JBOSS_HOME/PROJECT_PROPERTIES/abc.properties).PROJECT_PROPERTIES is the directory where we are keeping all the project related property files.I need to read this properties file from spring config.Earlier i was using the following approach.

```
<bean id="propertyOverrideConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:abc.properties" />
```

Now we moved all our properties file to JBOSS_HOME/PROJECT_PROPERTIES directory.

Please provide me some pointers how to access the properties file using spring.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out:

[How to read properties in spring](http://www.zparacha.com/how-to-read-properties-file-in-spring/)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the properties file path as a command line argument

```
<property name="location" value="${propertiesFile}" />
```

Then for the jvm parameters pass

```
-DpropertiesFile=my/configuration/file.properties
```